# android camera2 release resources doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, camera, release, android-camera2

I want to create a custom camera app in android. I have one activity that uses two fragments. One fragment is for camera and another is for show picture or video that was taken. When activity starts, It loads camera fragment. In preview of camera there is a button that uses for record video. In long press on button recording starts and after end of long press video recording stops and file is send to the fragment that show the video. In other word, at the end of long press on button I replace the camera fragment with a new fragment that show the result. In onPause of camera fragment I stopped the cameradevice but after some back and forth between fragments I can't use the camera at all. After some back and forth no camera application doesn't work in my phone and I have to restart my phone.

these are some codes of my camera fragment

```
@OnLongClick(R.id.capture)
public boolean captureLongPressed() {
    startRecord();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
    return true;
}

@OnTouch(R.id.capture)
public boolean captureOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (isRecordButtonLongPressed) {
            mIsRecording = false;
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            }
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onVideoRecorded(mVideoFileName);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void startRecord() {
    try {
        setupMediaRecorder();
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

            }
        }, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
 }
@Override
public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}

private void closeCamera() {
    if (null != mCameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in your `closeCamera` method?

Comment: I edited my post and added closeCamera. you can check it.